# Using an <div> with position: fixed; without disabling scrolling altogether? (CSS)

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-position, overlay

I'm trying to add a noise overlay using CSS:

```
.noise {
position: fixed;
top: -50%;
left: -50%;
right: -50%;
bottom: -50%;
width: 200%;
height: 200vh;
background: transparent url('../img/noise.png') repeat 0 0;
background-repeat: repeat;
animation: bg-animation .2s infinite;
opacity: .5;
visibility: visible; 
} 

@keyframes bg-animation {
0% { transform: translate(0,0) }
10% { transform: translate(-5%,-5%) }
20% { transform: translate(-10%,5%) }
30% { transform: translate(5%,-10%) }
40% { transform: translate(-5%,15%) }
50% { transform: translate(-10%,5%) }
60% { transform: translate(15%,0) }
70% { transform: translate(0,10%) }
80% { transform: translate(-15%,0) }
90% { transform: translate(10%,5%) }
100% { transform: translate(5%,0) }
}
```

I'm calling the code in HTML with `<div class="noise"></div>`

However, when I do this, it disables scrolling on my site altogether. It has something to do with *position:fixed;*. But what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Works here:
https://jsfiddle.net/sxbhqp7g/

Comment: Are all of your elements inside this fixed container? If so, that may be your problem.
The overlay should be a sibling of your main content.

Comment: always post you complete example code in a snippet and make sure it runs properly to show the issue so others can see the issue and edit it to help you.